# Change the height and width of a cell imageView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

Im using a UITableViewCell to hold text and an image but what i have done is:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"funny_man.png"];
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
cell.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
```

what it does is it creates the image from the top most corner to the bottom most corner of the left hand side. what i want it to do is be placed in the middle of the uitableviewcell with dimensions 30x30.

this is what it is outputting right now: http://postimg.org/image/hyzi2sz6b/

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to create a custom cell, and drag in a label and an image view. Give the image view a centerX, centerY, height, and width constraints. Create a custom class for the cell, and add IBOutlets for the label and imageView to the .h file (you don't need to add anything to the .m file). BE sure to change the class of the cell in IB to your custom class, and set the type to custom.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to set the frame of UIImageView

```
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake((cell.frame.size.width-30)/2, (cell.frame.size.height-30)/2, 30, 30);
```

This code will place the imageview in the center of your tableview cell.